# Copy last line in python file and modify it before adding a new line

Tags: python

I would like to check for a string "rele" in a python text file and if string is not present then copy the last line of the file and then modify it as below to add as a new entry.

Example:
Actual File: Where "rele" is not present

```
"123456",1,0,"mher",0,"N",01Jan1986 00:00,130:00,
"123456",1,1,"ermt",0,"N",01Jan1986 00:00,100:00,
"123456",1,2,"irbt",0,"N",01Jan1986 00:00,120:00,
```

Expected Output:

```
"123456",1,0,"mher",0,"N",01Jan1986 00:00,130:00,
"123456",1,1,"ermt",0,"N",01Jan1986 00:00,0:00,
"123456",1,2,"irbt",0,"N",01Jan1986 00:00,0:00,
"123456",1,3,"rele",0,"0000",01Jan1986 00:00,0:00,
```

Last entry of the file is similar to its previous except few changes to it's 3,4 and 6 columns.

My code:

```
  fp = open(srcEtab.txt, 'w')
  for line in lines:
      if 'rele' in line:
         foundRelOrPickup = True         
  if not foundRelOrPickup:
     fp1 = open ( 'srcEtab.txt',"w" )
     lineList = fp1.readlines()
     new_line = lineList[len(lineList)-1]
     fp1.write(new_line)
  fp.close()
  fp1.close()
```

Comment: Please demonstrate a reasonable effort to solve it yourself before anyone helps you further.

Comment: I have pasted the code I have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(yourFile) as f:
        lines =  f.readlines()
        if not any(map(lambda line: "rele" in line,lines)):
                last_line_words = lines[-1].split(',')
                last_line_words[2] = len(lines)
                last_line_words[3] = '"rele"'
                last_line_words[5] = '"0000"'
                lines.append(",".join([str(i) for i in last_line_words]))

        with open(otherFile, "w") as f1:
                for line in lines:
                        f1.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked as expected. Appreciate on your help,

Comment: I would like to write the output to the sample file. I believe changing the "otherFile" to "yourFile" will overwrite the original file with new line.

Comment: If you want to overwrite the input file, just replace otherFile with the name of the original file. You might want to unindent the second "with" statement, so you make sure that the file was closed before re-opening.